# PyYaml include double quotes inside value of a YAML field

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have YAML data that looks like this, this can't be changed:

```
...
my_field: "blah" -other_stuff
...
```

I'm trying to parse this verbatim, but pyYaml doesn't like it:
expected , but found ''
in "", line 12, column 207:

It sounds like it interprets the end of the double quotes as the end of the field, and I can't have anything after it.

Is there a way to "escape" those double quotes during parsing and keep the exact same string with double quotes? btw I'm doing a simple yaml.load().

Comment: I'm no YAML expert but I'm pretty sure that's not valid YAML, and I'm not sure why you're surprised that its failing to parse. Are you expecting the value to be `"blah" -other_stuff`?

Comment: agreed it doesn't look like valid YAML syntax It seems python YAML load is flagging these properly as it's less tolerant. Unfortunately we have yaml loaders in other platforms/languages which accept such values, that's why they currently exist

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert literal `"` characters in a YAML field, you can quote the entire field and then escape the `"` characters:

```yaml
my_field: "\"blah\" -other_stuff"
```